# Dynamically load PHP class(es)

Tags: php, class, oop, dynamic

I've seen countless examples of how to create a dynamically named class, but it does NOT seem to work for me:

```
$dynamic_id = 980; // typically passed in

$class = 'API\Recipes\Mix_' . $dynamic_id;
$dyn_class = new $class(); 
// results in: Fatal error: Class 'API\Recipes\Mix_980' not found

$class = "API\Recipes\Mix_{$dynamic_id}";
$dyn_class = new $class(); 
// results in: Fatal error: Class 'API\Recipes\Mix_980' not found

$static_class = new API\Recipes\Mix_980();
// results in: Fatal error: Class 'API\Recipes\Mix_980' not found
```

I'm trying to implement a strategy pattern with some dynamically loaded class based on the `$dynamic_id` value. All of the other classes load in this Slim Framework application. I'm just adding these new classes.

The path the files are located in is included in the `composer.json` to autoload & the interface I created to try to load this dynamically automatically worked, but not the dynamic class. PHPStorm gives me no errors on the file or directory.

PHPStorm finds the correct path to the class if I just load it manually, but it still says it cannot load the class with a fatal error saying class does not exist. As it stands, the entire contents of the class I'm trying to load is this:

```
<?php

namespace API\Recipes;

class Mix_980
{
  function __construct()
  {
    echo 'show me the money';
  }
}
```

I've never seen 'show me the money' & only get a PHP fatal error. I suspect it's something about the namespace, but it so basic that should work. I tried making Recipes a child directory of Recipe, renaming it, etc. Nothing seems to work! :(

```
<?php

namespace API\Recipe;

use API\Recipes\Mix_980;

class Mix implements MixInterface
{
  private $mixType;

  function __construct($item_type_id = 0)
  {
    //$class = "\API\Recipes\Mix_{$item_type_id}";
    //$class = 'API\Recipes\Mix_' . $item_type_id;
    //$class = new Mix_980();
    //$class = '\API\Recipes\Mix_980';
    //echo $class;
    $mix = new \API\Recipes\Mix_980();

  }
}
```

Directory structure:

```
B$ tree ./src/API/
./src/API/
├── Dir1
├── Dir2
├── . . . 
├── Recipe
│   ├── MixInterface.php
│   ├── Mix.php   // implements MixInterface
│   └── Recipe.php
├── Recipes
│   ├── Mix_123.php
│   ├── Mix_###.php
│   └── Mix_980.php
├── . . . 
└── Dir9
```

`composer.json` contents:

```
{
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "2.6.2",
    "php": ">=5.4.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "API": "src/"
    }
  },  
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

My system specs are:

```
B$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

B$ php -v
PHP 5.5.32 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2016 16:21:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: have you included composer's autoloader?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Yes, the autoloader is included. All other classes in the rest of my application work.

Comment: so, you can create an instance of `Mix` but even `$mix = new \API\Recipes\Mix_980();` doesn't works? can we take a look at your `composer.json`?

Comment: I just added the contents of composer.json. 

Correct. I can create an instance of Mix, but directly calling the namespace like that does not work. That's where I'm befuddled.

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l src/API/Recipes`?

Comment: `B$ ls -l src/API/Recipes`
`-rwxrwxr-- 1 www-data www-data 488 Apr 11 19:22 Mix_555.php*`
`-rwxrwxr-- 1 www-data www-data 121 Apr 11 21:06 Mix_980.php*`

Comment: I don't find any problem here - for debug purpose, can you put `var_dump(spl_autoload_functions());` instead of `$mix = new \API\Recipes\Mix_980();`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108865/discussion-between-laygo-and-federico).

Comment: I hope @Federico comes & submits an answer for me to accept. He was able to get me working.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$class = 'API\Recipes\Mix_' . $dynamic_id;
```

With this:

```
$class = '\API\Recipes\Mix_' . $dynamic_id;
```

By the way, i noticed that; this could be wrong too:

```
<?php

namespace API\Recipe;

use API\Recipes\Mix_980;

class Mix implements MixInterface
```

Correct way:

```
<?php

namespace API\Recipes;

use API\Recipes\Mix_980;

class Mix implements MixInterface
```

Comment: I tried doing your first tip of adding a leading slash with the same results before posting. The namespace suggestion in the second tip isn't incorrect, I've purposely set them in different namespaces.

Comment: @laygo Are you sure about you include your second code block to your first code where you called dynamic class ?

Comment: @laygo I mean before the this line of code `$dynamic_id = 980;` Did you write something like `include 'Mix_980.php';`

Comment: Manually including the files is not necessary with autoloading. The files are correctly autoloaded & the reason I was getting errors it turns out was my file names were NOT named exactly like class name, which is a requirement of PSR-4. I was not aware of that. My stuff is working now that I've figured it out. @Federico helped me get it working yesterday, but I came to the realization about the file names just a few mins ago.

Comment: I'm just waiting on @Federico to post an answer I can accept.  ;)